# Allow visitor see only 1 post on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible allow a visitor to see only a post?

I think it would be safer if it is restricted by IP instead by cookies.
For instance the plugin WP POST RATINGS of Lester Chan has the option to allow 1 voting by IP.

Comment: What is mean by post?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re not requiring a login, Cooke’s or local storage are you’re only viable solution.

IP checks are flawed in that any number of users on a local network will make requests from the same public IP address.

I understand your concern but most users are not incentivized or knowledgeable enough to understand that clearing their cookies would potentially allow a second “vote”.

So unless you go to a full Auth system you’re better off with cookies.

Comment: You right. A full Auth system would be a better option. Also , He would need to tracking ( User ID , Post ID ) in order to validate is a Post was already visited.

Comment: Great. My goal is show to the visitor only 1 post (whichever he chooses) as if he were logged in. If he try see a second post, he will only see an excerpt, Is there a wordpress plugin for this? thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Hide another pages for visitor. You can use "Anonymous Restricted Content" plugin for hide page for not logged in users.